Difficulty understanding grammar in 他に説明いるのって感じだけど

他に説明いるのって感じだけど、私服のときは左右から垂らした髪の先端が胸の上に乗っていることが多い。

The first part of this sentence really confuses me. My current interpretation of it is roughly "If another explanation's existence is felt".

いる is used for animate things (and in some cases inanimate things that move, as I recently learned). Shouldn't it be ある instead?

For 感じ, I treat as a masu-stem connective form, but I feel like it should probably be a noun instead.

I treated けど as a tone softener, but I feel like that's wrong too.


How would you interpret this sentence?


This いる is not the ichidan verb 居る but the godan verb 要る ("to be required/necessary").
Yes, this 感じ is a noun. ～という感じ(だ) is a common colloquial expression meaning I kinda feel ～ or It's like ～.
This けど simply "but".


他に説明いるのって感じだけど、

It's like "Is another explanation necessary?", but...
I doubt you need more explanation, but...



But if it means that, shouldn't it be something like 感じがない?

@Tree Here, 要るの is a rhetorical question, "Do you really need further explanation?"

I understand now! Thanks for your help, really appreciate it. By the way, would writing the いる here in kanji be strange?

@Leebo I know nothing about JPDB's algorithm, but when this verb is used, I think it's in kanji 80% of the time, and the percentage is nearly 100% in professionally-written materials. Otherwise, it could be confusing even to native speakers. On the other hand, いる meaning "to be present" is normally in hiragana.

@naruto Thanks for the additional information. jpdb is focused on things like light novels, visual novels, and anime, which may bias the results.
